# Is it possible to customize my own broadCastreceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

is it possible to create my own"cutomized" `broadCasrReceiver`?

I am connecting to a server and i want to keep track of the connectivity throughout the entire application. in other words, the App has many fragments and all of them need to have feedback about the connectivity state to the server i am connecting to, so that, if the connection to the server lost for any reason, then any `fragment` shoud be notified.

how to do so?

**Updat_1**:

**in the MainActivity**:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean isconnected = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", true);
        Log.d(TAG, "@broadCastReceiver(): isConnected: " + isconnected);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter());
}
```

**in the fragment, when there is Connection**:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("success", true);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: do want check the networkconnection with all fragments ?

Comment: @mohan i want to "register" the connectivity to the server iam connecting to, so that, while in any fragment in the App, if the connection lost, i can keep track of the situation and do an action based on it. yes i want to be able to check the connection in all the fragments. not to check with a local variable, but with something like a broadcast receiver.

Comment: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-getting-notified-of-connectivity-changes/ check this link it will help you

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, I think the following should do the job.

**Sender**

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.business.connection");
if (client.connect == true){
    i.putExtra("success", true);
}
else{
    i.putExtra("success", false);
}
this.context.sendBroadcast(i);     

/* Note: 'context' depends on where you're calling the code. 
   E.g. in a fragment you could just say 
   getActivity().sendBroadcast() */
```

**Receiver**

(This code is for an Activity but you could easily change to a Fragment by using the appropriate lifecycle methods).

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // DO something with the message
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra("success", true){
                // Connection successful 
            } else {
                // Connection NOT successful
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        // Register the receiver
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.business.connection"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Unregister the login receiver
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Having just seen  @mohan's solution, I that might be more suitable for you as it specifically deals with changes to connectivity. Mine is more of a general solution.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i think i almost understand what you posted, but i connect to a server using "client.connect(param1, param2,....param4). what i want to do is, if the "cient.connect" is successul, then such state should be broadcasted. how to do so. i wish i am clear

Comment: OK, I've updated the code to better explain it. There are several different approaches, e.g. you could have one intent for success and another for unsuccessful or you can  use one intent and add "extras" to say what the current state is (I've gone for the latter in the approach above).

Comment: thank you more clearer now, though i ahave a question please concerning the Sender and the Receiver. does the receiver which will be each fragment i have in the App, should implement the broadCastreceiver?...because the sender will be in a fragment and the receiver should be any different fragments

Comment: Yes, the receiving fragment(s) will need to register a broadcast receiver. You could put the receiver in its own class or, alternatively, you could subclass Fragment, put your broadcast receiver there and then extend that class throughout your app. That'll avoid you having to write the same code over and over again.

Comment: please see the update section above, i tried your answer but it did not work

Comment: OK. The code you've written isn't the quite the same as mine, and I don't know what else your app is doing, so I'm afraid I can't offer any more assistance. Perhaps you could take a look at the link supplied by @mohan on your question - it's quite similar to what I'm saying (only the intent is one generated by the OS). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code for detect internet connection and notify through broadcastintent

```
public class BroadCastSampleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

        if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

}

> and do not forget to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```